# How to sync node.js workspace changes using volume in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

I am using volumes in docker to sync changes with express app but changes are not visible. This is my config

```
version: '3.0' 

services:
  redis-server:
    image:  'redis'
  papp:
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
    volumes: 
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
```

docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD ./package.json ./package.json
RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source code changes won't be effective until node process inside the container reloads and picks up the changes.

In order to achieve this you have to use [nodemon](https://medium.com/better-programming/docker-in-development-with-nodemon-d500366e74df).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528257/1264304)