# How to configure API gateway in microservice architecture inside docker containers

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I am fairly new and was building a microservice using nodejs. My problem is that my API gateway is throwing errors when I start my containers using docker compose. I can send request to my service containers directly and the API's are responding. But when I forward them via API gateway I am having problems.
emphasized text

Following are my files in apiGateway directory:
Docker file:

```
FROM devopsfaith/krakend

COPY krakend.json /etc/krakend/
```

This is a image which is built and placed on github specifically for this gateway.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "extra_config": {
    "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-cors": {
      "allow_origins": ["*"],
      "allow_headers": ["*"],
      "expose_headers": ["Content-Length"],
      "max_age": "12h",
      "allow_methods": ["GET", "HEAD", "POST"]
    }
  },
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "output_encoding": "json",
  "name": "Gateway",
  "port": 3001,
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/auth/signup-customer",
      "method": "POST",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {},
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/auth/signup-customer",
          "host": ["http://auth-service:4000"],
          "method": "POST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/auth/signup-restaurant",
      "method": "POST",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {},
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/auth/signup-restaurant",
          "host": ["http://auth-service:4000"],
          "method": "POST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/auth/login",
      "method": "POST",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {},
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/auth/login",
          "host": ["http://auth-service:4000"],
          "method": "POST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/auth/check",
      "method": "GET",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {},
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/auth/check",
          "host": ["http://auth-service:4000"],
          "method": "GET"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/products/_search",
      "method": "POST",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {},
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/products/_search",
          "host": ["http://elasticsearch:9200"],
          "method": "POST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/health",
      "method": "GET",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {
        "github.com/devopsfaith/krakend/proxy": {
          "static": {
            "data": {
              "status": "OK"
            },
            "strategy": "always"
          }
        }
      },
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/fake",
          "encoding": "json",
          "sd": "static",
          "method": "GET",
          "extra_config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The above code is a json file with my endpoints. Currently I am only test authentication api endpoints.

**Auth Service**
Docker file:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

**Docker compose file**

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-gateway:
    build: "./gateway"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

  auth-service:
    build: "./authService"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - DB_URL = mongodb://db/MagicMeal
    volumes:
      - ./authService:/app

  item-service:
    build: "./itemService"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - DB_URL = mongodb://db/MagicMeal
    volumes:
      - ./itemService:/app

  user-service:
    build: "./userService"
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    environment:
      - DB_URL = mongodb://db/MagicMeal
    volumes:
      - ./userService:/app
#   db:
#     image: mongo:latest
#     ports:
#       - 27017:27017
#     volumes:
#       - ./MagicMeal:/data/db

# volumes:
#   MagicMeal:
```

Below is the error image
In the image you can see an error that says connection refuse. Now this error comes when I call my api using the following url : "http://localhost:3001/auth/check" as this is my api gateway address which reroutes the request to "localhost:4000/auth/check" .My gateway is on the port 3001 and my aut service on port 4000. But if i simply hit "localhost:4000/auth/check" i get a response. But the same request initiated via gate gives error
[click here to open the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vQrE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put service names and service exposed ports (both defined in `docker-comose.yml`)  in api gateway endpoints configuration. For example, `auth-service:4000` instead of `localhost:4000`.

When you succeed to connect to `localhost:4000` you connect to you docker host (your machine, vm) which routes the requests to container directly.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: please add the updated api gateway configuration to the question so that your issue will be reproducible

Comment: I updated the config file. Kindly, have a look.

Comment: hi, i didn't succeed to reproduce the issue because `docker-compose build` fails...

please share fully reproducible code base on github and `docker-compose` commands you use to reproduce the  issue (build imaeges, run images, send request...).

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. After I reconfigured the docker compose file according to the same naming conventions as you told me, the error persisted because for some reason when i ran docker compose it did not rebuild the image and used the old image. So, i deleted the current image and re-built it and started compose. It worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I had another question. I want to be able edit my code while my containers are running and see the live changes after i save it. How is that possible. Every time i make a change in my code i have to restart my containers or compose if using collectively.

Comment: happy you resolved the issue. to use live reload of node.js code inside running container see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58528257/1264304) answer